# cherrypy.request.body.read() error

Tags: python, request, cherrypy

I'm having some problems accessing http requests' bodies with the CherryPy framework.
I'm using CherryPy 3.2.0 on a x86_64 Arch Linux machine w/ Python3 and Aptana Web Studio IDE.

When I try to access a request's body via the usual cherrypy.request.body.read(), i get the error

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpreqbody.py", line 450, in read
return self.fp.read(size, fp_out)
TypeError: read() takes at most 2 positional arguments (3 given)
```

The code causing the error is:

```
import cherrypy

class Test:
    def index(self):
        print(cherrypy.request.body.read())
        #print(cherrypy.request.body.readline()) <- this works!
    return 'HelloWorld'
index.exposed = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(Test())
```

However, using

```
cherrypy.request.body.readline() or cherrypy.request.body.readlines(n)
```

instead of

```
cherrypy.request.body.read()
```

i can skim through the request's body just fine. I tried googling for a solution but found none. Considering i'm a total python newbie, there must be something i am doing wrong, but what?

Thanks in advance for your precious help.

Comment: What does `print(type(cherrypy.request.body.fp))` give you? (Just before the `print` line.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `body.read()` method works properly only if the request body was processed, which happens only when `request.process_request_body` is True (it is by default) and when the request method is in `request.method_with_bodies` which is only PUT and POST by default, but not GET (which you probably used when requesting the page with a browser).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! The exception thrown must be one of the least descriptive I have ever seen...